# Not able to solve Thevinin voltage

Tags: norton

I am trying to solve this circuit.Can you please tell me if I am in the correct direction. 
[image: solution]

Comment: Can the thevinin voltage be just 50 ohm multiplied by 50 A current.? Taking pt.B as ground.

Comment: Why do ask for "Thevenin voltage" if you actually want Norton current?

Comment: Two hints: instead of doing node or even mesh analysis I prefere (as a human) to solve such problems in one of the two following ways: (1) either do serveral circuit transformation that turn the circuit into the Norton (or Thevenin) equivalent. If that is not easily possible: (2) (a) calculate short circuit current from A to B (it is the Norton current). (b) calculate open circuit voltage between A and B (it is the Thevenin volatge). Thevenin *and* Norton resistance then is open circuit voltage divided by short circuit current.

Comment: Thank you sir.say if I short circuit A and B then will the current source of 50A contribute to the current.(I say that because its a current source and not an element)I.e: x + 50A. ?

Comment: @Anupam Bisht: it will contribute full 50A (the 50 Ohm resistor **in series** has no effect on the **current**).

Comment: Also recognize that the full 50A does not flow through the 20 ohm resistor. (It divides between the 20 and 10 ohm resistors).

Answer (score 1):

.
[image: schematic]

You calculated the value for I1 correctly. It is 30 A.
But you cannot use a loop where there's (VA-VB).
You have a loop with R2, R3, R4, and I1 instead. If you use this loop, you get the correct value for the Thevenin voltage which is 1900 V.

Answer (score 0):

I used mesh analysis on the leftmost loop and the current contribution from that loop turned out to be 30A counter clockwise. Hence, a net current of 20A would flow through the 20 ohm resistor in the downward direction. Now applying Kirchhoff's second law along a path passing through that resistor, the Thevenin voltage turns out to be 1900V as opposed to 2500V along the path passing through the current source. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have to calculate A:the output short circuit current; B:the resistance between A and B when V1 = I1 = 0 . 
A: Short circuit current :
1- I1 = 0 ; Isc_v1 = V1 / (R1 + (R2 // R3)) * R2 / (R2 + R3) ;
   R2 // R3 = R2 * R3 / (R2 + R3)
2- V1 = 0 ; Ics_I1 = I1
==> Isc = Isc_v1 + Isc_I1 
B: Rab = R3 + R1 // R2 = R3 + R1 * R2 / (R1 + R2) ; the internal resistance of I1 is infinity (open circuit) ; the internal resistance of V1 is 0 ; R4 have no effect on Vab
the equivalent circuit is a current source of Isc // Rab

to calculate a equivalent circuit of Voltage source with serial resistance : from the last results : Calculate the open circuit voltage : Voc = Isc * Rab ; 
connect a voltage source of Voc in serial with Rab

Answer (score 0):

Your loop equation for the Thevenin voltage is wrong. It looks like you're trying to go in a loop from \$V_B\$ to \$V_A\$, then left through the 30-ohm resistor and down through the 20-ohm resistor. That's fine, but for some reason you put the 50-ohm resistor on the other side of the equation! Here's what the actual loop looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fowSe3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You don't need to follow a branch to talk about the voltage between \$V_B\$ and \$V_A\$! So your loop equation would be:

$$(V_A - V_B) = (50 \mathrm A \times 30 \Omega) + (30 \mathrm A \times 20 \Omega)$$

Or, alternately:

$$(V_A - V_B) - (50 \mathrm A \times 30 \Omega) - (30 \mathrm A \times 20 \Omega) = 0$$

Usually in this case you can define \$V_B\$ to be the ground node (0 V), so the equation would just have \$V_A\$ instead of \$(V_A - V_B)\$.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this.
I suggest to simplify the circuit by following transformation steps that are also shown in the picture:

1. transform the Thevenin source (V1 + R1) into a Norton source I2 = V1 / R1.
2. transform parallel combination of R1 and R2 to one resistor R5
3. transform the Norton source back into a Thevenin source V3 = I2 * R5
4. transform series combination of R5 and R3 to one resistor R6 = R5 + R3

[image: transformation steps]

Now you have a simple single loop circuit.
You know V3 and you know the current through R6 (it is 50A).
Calculate the voltage across R6 and add it to V3 to get the voltage between the two nodes.